# A 32-bit unsigned integer in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, int, unsigned

I am developing LiveJournal.com client and i have one question. Can u, please, explain what does it mean?

scalar Relevant when security is usemask. A 32-bit unsigned integer representing which of the user's groups of friends are allowed to view this post. Turn bit 0 on to allow any defined friend to read it. Otherwise, turn bit 1-30 on for every friend group that should be allowed to read it. Bit 31 is reserved.

What am i need to add in NSMutableDictionary if i want to see, for example, group with id=6? I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security implementation works by authorizing or no a *group* of friends to read a journal/text.

This assume there is a maximum of 30 possible groups, as bit-0 is specific, and bit-31 is reserved.

The security is coded on an `unsigned int`, meaning 32 bits, of which bit0 to bit31 have a special meaning.

- the LSb, bit0, if set to `1` allows any friend the read access.
- if bit0 is `0`, it means that the next 30 bits, bit1 to 30, are checked to see if the group `i` (from bit `i`) has read access (bit set to `1`) or no (bit set to `0`).

An `unsigned int` can be represented as

```
  bit 31                     bit 0
  v                              v
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

for instance the decimal value of 11 (0...01011, or 8+3) is represented as

```
  00000000000000000000000000001011
```

where bit 0, 1 and 3 are set to 1, the others are set to 0.

So, to check if a *friend* has access to a journal, take the journal access bits, for instance

```
  11000000000000000000000000001011
```

you see that the first bit is 1, so all groups (all friends) are authorized.

If the access would be

```
  11000000000000000000000000001010
```

the first bit is 0, so you have to check the group number against the access above. Say the group number is 1, you check against the access above

```
  11000000000000000000000000001010
                                1
                                ^
                        group one
```

and you see that the group 1 is authorized. If you would have

```
  11000000000000000000000000001000
```

the group 1 is *not* authorized.

For groups 3 and 30, the access is also authorized:

```
  11000000000000000000000000001000
   *                          *
```

(The MSb. bit31 is set to `1`, but its value is reserved, so you shouldn't bother its value)

Comment: WOW. BIG BIG BIG thank you! Now everything is working! U are the best!)))

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it deserves it :-)